# trying to upgrade and then "I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from ..."

Tags: upgrade, initramfs

I tried to `sudo apt-get upgrade` but this is what I got

```
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda5
I: (UUID=956d301b-3deb-421f-bf5b-396982c5c8ac)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-46-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda5
I: (UUID=956d301b-3deb-421f-bf5b-396982c5c8ac)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.14_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Difficult - check if there is still space left in the boot partition with `df -h`.

Comment: You have a couple of things there. The 'attempt to resume' is not really a problem and is easy to get rid of. The error is a completely separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error message

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.14_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

points to an installation failure of linux-firmware. The initramfs output looks fine to me. Can you provide the full log? Also check that you have enough space in  `/boot` and `/var/cache`.